# Plot Clusters with Color from Hierarchical Clustering

Tags: python, matplotlib, hierarchical-clustering

```
#Plot the figure

plt.figure(1);
plt.clf();
plt.scatter(data[0,:],data[1,:]);
plt.xlabel('x');
plt.ylabel('y');
plt.title("Plot of all points from CURE dataset")
```

[image]

```
#Make dendrogram 

Y=pdist(data,'euclid');
distances=squareform(Y);
c=linkage(data,method='single');
dendrogram(Z);
idx = fcluster(Z,5,'maxclust');
```

[image]

I want to color the points according to which cluster they belong to, how can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the answer. Simply take the `idx` values, which represent the clusters, and plot using this command:

```
plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=idx, cmap='rainbow')
```

[image]